JSON logs in JDK6 legacy application
We have a Struts project developed in JDK6. Need json log file with username, threadname, servicename using log4j1.2. Please suggest with sample code.
Tried CustomJSON layout but only static values are appearing in the json log file. How to get the dynamic values in log file.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
